# Keep session in koa on multiple servers

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, session, koa

I have multiple koa servers with a load balancer, using passport login. I would like to keep the session across all servers.

My first attempt was to set the session storage to be in mysql database, but this caused the server to call mysql on each request, thus causing performance issues.

I would like to keep the session object in the RAM of each server, and if the user gets redirected to another server by the load balancer and the server doesn't recognize the cookie, I would like it to fallback to a database and load the data into its RAM too.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To store a session, you can use some key-value in-memory databases, in most cases it is either a [redis](http://redis.io/), [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.org/). You need to allocate server, where you will installed appreciated software and then configrure koa to use them. I would like to advice you an redis, following [lib](https://github.com/koajs/koa-redis) and [example](https://github.com/koajs/koa-redis/blob/master/example.js) implementation.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, but as I wrote, I tried using centralized storage, but this caused a request to the storage each time. I would like the centralized storage to be a fallback iff the session is not in the current server.

Comment: @AviTshuva this storage are designed to be session storage, because they are also in-memory and faster than MySQL you've tried.

Comment: But they are still on a remote server, and this is an overhead I would like to avoid, except for cases in which I must do it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very late, but most load-balances have the option of ["sticky sessions"](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)(see Session persistence), meaning that requests from the same IP are routed to the same process. Maybe try this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use koa-session https://github.com/koajs/session.

Here is a good tutorial http://www.zev23.com/2014/03/koajs-tutorial-authenticate-with_7.html

The complete app.js copied from the tutorial.

```
"use strict"

const
  Router = require('koa-router'),
  passport = require('./auth'),
  session = require('koa-sess'),
  redisStore = require('koa-redis'),
  koa = require('koa'),
  app = koa();

//Middleware: request logger
function *reqlogger(next){
  console.log('%s - %s %s',new Date().toISOString(), this.req.method, this.req.url);
  yield next;
}
app.use(reqlogger);

//Initialize session
app.keys=['koa-tutorial'];
app.use(session({
  cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 5},
  store : redisStore()
}));

//Initialize passport with session
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(Router(app));

app.get('/', function *(){
  console.log('Express-style example');
  this.body = "This is root page ('/')";
});

const publicRouter = new Router();

//Configure /auth/github & /auth/github/callback
publicRouter.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github', {scope: ['user','repo']}));
publicRouter.get('/auth/github/callback',
  passport.authenticate('github', {successReturnToOrRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/'})
);

app.use(publicRouter.middleware());

//Secures routes
const securedRouter = new Router();

//Middleware: authed
function *authed(next){
  if (this.req.isAuthenticated()){
    yield next;
  } else {
    //Set redirect path in session
    this.session.returnTo = this.session.returnTo || this.req.url;
    this.redirect('/auth/github');
  }
}

securedRouter.get('/app', authed, function *(){
  this.body = 'Secured Zone: koa-tutorial\n' + JSON.stringify(this.req.user, null, '\t');
});

securedRouter.get('/app2', authed, function *(){
  this.body = 'Secured Zone: koa-tutorial APP2\n'
});

app.use(securedRouter.middleware());

app.use(function *(){
  this.body = 'Hello World';
});

app.listen(3000);
```